# How to change the backgroundColor of IndexBar for UITableView in iOS7?

Tags: uitableview, indexing, ios7

I need to change the `backgroundcolor` of `IndexBar` for `UITableView` in `iOS7`.

For Default , `IndexBar` backgroundColor is white and `textColor` is blue like following pic.

[image]

I want to change the backgroundColor to `clearColor` and `textColor` to red.

How can i do that in iOS7?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sorry. I got my answer for my own question.

Here is codes

```
[[self tableView] setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[self tableView] setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```